# dplyr merge dataframes by common row values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two `dataframes` from two different years, and I would like to merge them to a single `dataframe` based on common row values from column `code` present in both the `dataframes`.

How can I do this using `dplyr` in `R`?

```
DF1

Code Count_2020
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
E    5
F    6

DF2

Code Count_2021
A    4
B    8
C    6
D    8
E    10
F    12
G    2
H    3
I    4
J    5
```

Comment: Try `inner_join(DF1, DF2)`

Comment: @arkun, it works, cheers!

Comment: @akrun, no worries, just waiting for `stackoverflow's` time limit to end, before I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(DF1, DF2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
merge(DF1,DF2)
```

Outuput:

```
  Code Count_2021 Count_2020
1    A          4          1
2    B          8          2
3    C          6          3
4    D          8          4
5    E         10          5
6    F         12          6
```

Comment: Base R brother. I tried to learn pivoting with base R and I guess this is the hardest thing ever check this link: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/610313_0328bc102fc1468ba34a9e2ca4c295be.html